# Has anyone implemented a replacement for string.h using a struct to store the string and length?

Tags: c, string

In the C standard library, strings are implemented using an array of chars, terminated by a null character: '\0'. Such ASCIZ strings lead to inefficiency because every time we need to know the length of a string, we need to iterate over it looking for '\0'.

The way around this is to store the length of the string when we create it, e.g. using a struct as follows:

```
typedef struct cstring_ {
    size_t nchars;
    char chars[0];
} cstring;
```

Has anyone made a shared library implementing the string.h functions, but using a struct instead of `char *` to pass strings around?

If not, is there a specific reason why this would be a bad idea?

Comment: "is there a specific reason why this would be a bad idea" - if your program spends only a small proportion of its time in `strlen`, then it's probably a waste of your time and a waste of code complexity. That would make it a bad idea. If your program does a *lot* of `strcat` then you could see a benefit from storing the length, or then again you could rewrite the code to use something like (non-standard) [stpcpy](http://refspecs.freestandards.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/baselib-stpcpy-3.html)

Comment: Have you tried using C++, which is full of these kinds of efficient data structures?  :-)

Comment: I think writing your own string class is a rite of passage for a lot of programmers

Comment: For a general use string class, a `size_t nCapacity` is useful too

Answer (score 5):

There are probably dozens of those. Have a look at [Glib's GString](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-Strings.html) for example.

Answer (score 3):

> Has anyone made a shared library implementing the string.h functions, but using a struct instead of `char *` to pass strings around?

I did.

11 years ago, when I was learning C: I reimplemented the whole <string.h> library, making sure reallocations were used whenever more room was needed in the string.

But then, it was for learning purposes (since, then, I moved to C++ and now use std::string).

> is there a specific reason why this would be a bad idea?

I guess it can be a good idea to try it yourself: This way, using the right API, you can memorize along the string both its length, the size of the buffer, perhaps even a reference counter if you want to try playing with copy-on-write concepts. Your string will be more complex, but more efficient for some cases than the default. And this is a good learning experience.

But for production code, as always, either you are very very experienced, or you should try to find a library that will do that better than you will.

I know some production-ready implementations using this alternative string.

[Mat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328526/has-anyone-implemented-a-replacement-for-string-h-using-a-struct-to-store-the-str/6328563#6328563) already mentioned the GLib's GString.

If you're coding for Windows, Microsoft's [BSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221069.aspx) (and its C++ wrapper [bstr_t](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6.aspx)) could solve your problem: They are can be read like a `const char *` string, and they use [SysAllocString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) and its sister functions, [SysFreeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221481.aspx), etc..

You can use them for production code, or for learning purposes, learn from them.

Answer (score 1):

From the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html)

> Despite its popularity, the technique
>   is also somewhat notorious: Dennis
>   Ritchie has called it ``unwarranted
>   chumminess with the C
>   implementation,'' and an official
>   interpretation has deemed that it is
>   **not strictly conforming with the C
>   Standard**, although it does seem to
>   work under all known implementations.
>   (Compilers which check array bounds
>   carefully might issue warnings.)

Also I think it should be `char chars[1];`.

Comment: From that page, "C99 introduces the concept of a flexible array member, which allows the size of an array to be omitted if it is the last member in a structure, thus providing a well-defined solution". If you need to support strict C89 as well as C99, you can use a macro to give a flexible array member in C99, and a 1-sized array elsewhere (that you could try to check the compiler docs on each new platform to confirm it will work, or just assume it will).

Comment: No it shouldn't be `[1]` but `[]` as is mentioned at the end of the FAQ that you are pointing to. "Flexible array" member as of C99 is the way to go. Has the FAQ well summarizes there seems to be no way to do this strictly conforming with C89. @Steve got me by 28 sec :)

Comment: Checking for C99 is the way to go; there are compilers that still don't support C99 (cl).

Comment: Getting a conforming C compiler is the way to go. Both GCC and Intel C are available for Windows.

Comment: @larsmans While that is preferable, it may not always be an option

Comment: @larsmans: Are conforming compilers available for all embedded platforms?  If one has a $60,000 piece of industrial equipment with an Acme 9000 processor, and nobody's written or maintained any cross-compilers for that platform in the last 15 years, but the old compiler still works well for the dialect of C it supports, "getting a conforming C compiler" may be easier said than done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a bunch of libraries that do this, including [Glib](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-Strings.html), [BString](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/), [VStr](http://www.and.org/vstr/) and others. The problems is that they're generally quite awkward to use, or at the least require learning non-standard APIs to handle strings. (C++'s `std::string` would be an example of string handling done right, but it depends on a lot of C++ features.)

If you're afraid of the cost of `strlen`, then you should compute the length of the string "manually" while doing operations on them and perform most operations with `memcpy` and direct access to the characters. That's only useful in tight loops, though.

Comment: I just tried the three libraries you mention and BString seems to do the job -- simple, BSD licensed, easy to compile and use. Glib seems like using a sledgehammer to swat a fly! It seems like I didn't research my question well enough, because the VStr maintainer has a quite [comprehensive list of C string handling libraries](http://www.and.org/vstr/comparison).

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something like this in one of my projects (however, I used class instead of struct). It is easy to implement. Also it is good idea to store everything, including length, in one memory area, and represent a string as a pointer to the the beginning of string data itself.

Answer (score 0):

I find that whenever I need the length of a "string" what I really need is to know if the string is empty or whether I've reached its end. Other times I need to iterate through the chars anyway so I can just as easily check for NULL.

So, let me rephrase your question: is there a specific reason you think this is a *better* idea?

Comment: In `strcat`, you need to know where the end of the string is, but you don't need to iterate through its characters.

Comment: For example, you have a code doing a lot of concatenation of strings, and you want to avoid unnecessary reallocs. Not having to `strlen` each string is a performance bonus (O(1) instead of O(n)).

Comment: The reason for the question, is not just to do with computational efficiency but also to do with DRY principles and code cleanliness. It just seems better design, since we know the length of a string when we allocate it, to store the length for subsequent recall. It seems inelegant to have to compute the length at some later point, even if we can do it efficiently.

Comment: @Jamie Bullock: If it solves a problem you have then by all means store the length; just don't do it on the off-chance than one day you might need it.

Comment: @Jamie: DRY means repeating yourself in code, or in data structures. "Getting the length of a string" is still getting it, regardless of whether `strlen` is implemented to scan for a nul byte, or just to load an integer value out of a structure, and your code will probably contain the same number of uses of `strlen` either way. Nothing in DRY says that the *machine* shouldn't have to repeat *itself*, and caching every value for later reuse is not in general DRY, it eventually leads to redundant data storage.

Comment: ... DRY code might even be very inefficient, by passing work from the programmer to the machine. I think the two are almost orthogonal concerns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a bad idea, actually the c++ implementation of string is just like you said. And there is also c implementation such as gstring in glib. It is almost a standard library in linux world. I think the reason why it's not a standard c lib is because c lang has too long history and most of the developers and projects are used to orignal c style string.